# Guarantee that the intersection of a family of sets satisfies $P$ when every member satisfies $P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

1) Suppose we are given a family of sets $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ indexed by a set $\Lambda$ of arbitrary cardinal. Suppose that in addition the sets $A_\alpha$ are endowed with some property $P$. Are there any conditions on $P$ (and a priori only on $P$) sufficient to assure that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda} A_\alpha$ also satisfies $P$?

It is well known that this is false in general, as is exemplified by a countable descending chain of nonempty sets, whose intersection can be added to the chain but may be empty.

2) Are there better sufficient conditions on $P$ if we know that the sets $A_\alpha$ are endowed with certain fixed algebraic structure?

For example, if the $A_\alpha$ are ideals of an associative algebra, the condition $P$ of being an essential ideal is still a counterexample: in $\mathbb{Z}$ every nonzero ideal is essential and their intersection is $0$.

---

The initial motivation for the question is the following: consider a ring and a property $P$ satisfied by a family of its (left, right or two-sided) ideals, which holds in addition for arbitrary intersections of the family. Then we can consider the partially ordered set of the ideals satisfying $P$ and apply (the descending version of) Zorn's Lemma to it. Then there are minimal ideals for property $P$ among these ideals, and in fact there can be only one, since if $I,J$ are two of them, then $I=I\cap J=J$ by minimality and $P(I),P(J)\Rightarrow P(I\cap J)$. In this way we can define a unique object for the ring, which may have further interesting features (depending on $P$). Hence it would be nice to count with a procedure to generate this kind of properties.

Comment: May the downvoter explain why the downvote? How can the question be improved?

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for the downvote, there is a [chatroom explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649).

Answer (score 2):

For (1), a property $P$ which does not hold of the empty set satisfies your condition if and only if there is some set $X$ such that for all sets $Y$, $P(Y)$ implies $X\subseteq Y$.

One direction is easy; for the other, suppose there were no such $X$. Fix some $Y$ such that $P(Y)$ holds (note: $P$ can't be empty, otherwise $\emptyset$ works for $X$). Now for each element $a$ of $Y$ we can, by assumption, find some $Z_a$ with $P(Z)$ but $\{a\}\not\subset Z_a$; taking the intersection of these yields the empty set.

On the other hand, consider the property $P(Y)$="Either $Y$ contains $1$ and $2$, or $Y$ is finite and contains $1$." Then $P$ certainly doesn't hold of the emptyset, and the intersection of arbitrarily many sets satisfying $P$ still satisfies $P$; but there is no $X$ such that $P(Y)$ is *equivalent* to "$X\subseteq Y$." So we really can only get "$P(Y)$ implies $X\subseteq Y$."

For (2), there are plenty of properties - being a subgroup of a group, being an ideal of a ring, being a topology on $X$ at least as fine as some $\tau$, being a (possibly empty) convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - which are closed under arbitrary intersection. Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: Your characterization is nice, but for (1) I was really thinking about a sufficient condition on $P$ and only on $P$, that is, without any a priori condition on the family $A_\alpha$ (of course, satisfying $P$ would a posteriori imply certain properties of the family, as the one you stated). For (2) I was moving on similar grounds: are there general sufficient conditions on $P$ (and only on $P$) that can be assured if we know a priori that the family of sets is endowed with some fixed algebraic structure?

Comment: I will add some algebraic context to the question, although my curiosity about the subject is broader than my initial interest on it

Comment: My sufficient condition is: "If there is some set $X$ such that, for all $Y$, $P(Y)$ holds only if $X\subseteq Y$." How is this not just a condition on $P$?

Comment: I realize that I have not defined "to be a condition on" and it is not a crystal clear notion. What I mean is the following: given a $P$, it may be the case that your sufficient condition can be tested on $P$ just from its definition (as in your example), but it may also be the case that you need to check a condition for every $Y$ for every fixed $X$, and hence you have to check it in particular for every $A_\alpha$ (and their intersection). I mean something (informally) like "effectively computable" from the definition, not involving the family in the computation in any way.

Answer (score 1):

First note that if we have a collection of intersection-compatible $P_i,i\in I$, then their "intersection" $$\tag0P(X)\equiv\forall i\in I\colon P_i(X)$$ is also intersection-compatible: If $P_i(A_\alpha)$ for all $i$ and $\alpha$, then $P_i(\bigcap A_\alpha)$ for all $i$. (On the other hand, already $P_1(X)\lor P_2(X)$ need not be intersection-compatible if $P_1,P_2$ are).
Hence we can look for "elementary" properties that are intersection-compatible.

The more or less obvious cases of such intersection-compatible $P$ are of the form
$$\tag1 P_{a,b}(X)\ \equiv\ a\subseteq X\to b\in X $$
and closure under algebraic operations is an example of this: $\{x,y\}\subseteq X\to x*y\in X$.
Note that $a\subseteq X$ can be rewritten as $a\in\mathcal P(X)$ and that $a\in X$ can be expressed as $\{a\}\subseteq X$. So one might wonder if the antecedent can be repaced by $a\in F(X)$ for suitable $F$ apart from $\mathcal P$ and the identity. The first thing to test would be $\bigcup$, but that does not work: If $a\ne a'$ then  $a\in\bigcup\{\{a\}\}$ and $a\in\bigcup\{\{a,a'\}\}$, but $a\notin \bigcup(\{\{a\}\}\cap\{\{a,a'\}\})=\emptyset$. The next thing to try would be concatenations such as $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$, but that does not introduce anything new.

A reformulation and mild generalization of $(1)$ would be
$$\tag{1'}P_{A,B}(X)\equiv (\forall x\colon A(x)\to x\in X)\to (\forall x\colon B(x)\to  x\in X) $$
and honestly it seems I can't imagine anything intersection-compatible not of this form.